# How to prove that A is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

So I was given this question in my exam, and it is by no mean a homework.

Let A  = \begin{pmatrix} 5 & 1 & 0 \\  1 &  5 &  0  \\ 0 & 0  &  6  \end{pmatrix}

(a) Find the eigenvalues and a basis for each of the eigenspaces of A
answer: $\lambda_1 = \lambda_3 = 6$ and $\lambda_2 = 4$

The corresponding basis are:
For $\lambda_1 = \lambda_3 = 6$:

Span =  \begin{pmatrix}  1   \\ 1     \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} and 
\begin{pmatrix} 0   \\ 0     \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}

For $\lambda_2=  4$:
Span =  \begin{pmatrix} -1   \\ 1   \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}

now for the part (b):
Show that $A$ is diagonalizable. Find an invertible matrix $P$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $P^{-1} A P = D$ (do not verify).

So I assumed that since there is 2 distinct eigenvalues and 3 linearly independent eigenvectors, $A$ is diagonalizable. How do I continue? Should I assume that the entries of the diagonal matrix $D$ is the eigenvalues and proceed from there?

Thank you.

Comment: You have done the work.   Form $P$ from the 3 LI column eigenvectors you derived.  Then $P^{-1} A P= D,$ where $D=\text{diag}(6,6,4).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvectors are the columns of the matrix $P$.

You have:
$$
A=PDP^{-1}
$$
with:
$$
P=
\pmatrix{-1&0&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&0}
$$
$$
D=
\pmatrix{4&0&0\\0&6&0\\0&0&6}
$$

$$
P^{-1}=
\pmatrix{-1/2&1/2&1\\0&0&1\\1/2&1/2&0}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your anwer, however i was wondering if the order we insert the eigenvalues in D matter, my entries where (6,6,4) ?

Comment: Use the columns eigenvectors in the same order as corrisponding eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

You have done the hard part. You need only organize it correctly. To do so, simply note that
$$
A=P\Lambda P^{-1}
$$
where
\begin{align*}
P
&= \begin{pmatrix}-1&0&1\\1&0&1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}
&
\Lambda
&=\begin{pmatrix}4&0&0\\0&6&0\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
The columns of $P$ are the eigenvectors of $A$ and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix whose diagonal consists of the eigenvalues of $A$ ordered to coincide with the eigenvectors listed in $P$.